# .net InterBase FireBird SQL

Tags: .net, firebird, transactions, interbase

I am using InterBase and FireBird SQL in C# .net Enviroment.

I would Like to use Transaction Scope in my program.

How to do that Effectively with InterBase-FireBird ?

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firebird you have to use the [Firebird .net data provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=netprovider).

You can start by reading the [documentation](http://firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/transaction-isolation-levels.html) about transaction

Comment: I think the original question was asking whether Firebird supported  implicit transaction flow management provided using the System.Transactions.TransactionScope class. Your links don't address that question.